# Ignore first loop result

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a a FOR loop that lists all files within a certain directory. One of the results is also INDEX.PHP, a result which I don't need. It's the first result/entry of the loop...

Is there any way to skip this first result and start looping from the second one?
Please help.

```
    <?php
$myDirectory = opendir('.');

while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) 
{
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

closedir($myDirectory);

$indexCount = count($dirArray);
echo '<h5>There are ' . $indexCount . ' files in the Media Center</h5>';

sort($dirArray);

echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th width="33%" align="center" class="admin_th" style="border-radius: 10px 0 0 0">Download</th>';
echo '<th width="33%" align="center" class="admin_th">Filetype</th>';
echo '<th width="33%" align="center" class="admin_th" style="border-radius: 0 10px 0 0">Filesize (in bytes)</th>';
echo '</tr>';

for($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
{
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
    {
        echo '<tr><td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-even"><a href="' . $dirArray[$index] . '">' . $dirArray[$index] . '</a></td>';
        echo '<td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-odd">';
        echo strtoupper(substr($dirArray[$index], -3));
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-even">';
        echo filesize($dirArray[$index]);
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of doing it:

- You can start one index later:

Instead of `for($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) { ...}`,
do

`for($index = 1; $index < $indexCount; $index++) { ...}`

- You can also add a condition:

for example:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
  if ($dirArray[$index] == 'INDEX.PHP') continue;
  // rest of the loop
}
```

---

But they are a few ways you can improve your code. Instead of using `opendir()` and `readdir()`, you can just use scandir like this:

```
foreach (scandir('.') as $file) {

}
```

But it looks like you want to grab some media file and display them. So an even better solution would be to use the [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function, like this:

```
foreach (glob("*{.mp3,.mp4,.jpg,.png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you see it what you don't want, place a [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement which backs the loop to for condition.

Answer (score 0):

Does the loop return the files as objects? then you could just add an if statement to the filename parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
    for($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
    {
        //skip first entry
        if($index == 0) continue;
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
        {
            echo '<tr><td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-even"><a href="' . $dirArray[$index] . '">' . $dirArray[$index] . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-odd">';
            echo strtoupper(substr($dirArray[$index], -3));
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td width="33%" align="center" class="admin_td-even">';
            echo filesize($dirArray[$index]);
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case it would be better to use `for($index = 1; $index < $indexCount; $index++)`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the desired file by comparing name of the current file with desired. For example, you can do it in list retrieving:

```
$myDirectory = opendir('.');

while( false!==($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) ) 
{
    if( strtolower($entryName)=='index.php' )continue;
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

closedir($myDirectory);
```

Do not rely on the index (number of file), because your `index.php` may be not first in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
 if(index == 0) continue;
 // other stuff
}
```